# Backbonejs + MarionetteJD - Converting Backbone list view to MarionetteJS Collection View

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

My BackboneJS "list item view" is defined as follows:

```
  class TagListView extends Backbone.View
    el:"#tags"

    render: =>
      @collection = new TagCollection
      @collection.fetch_data
        order_by : "name"
      , =>
        @on_success()

    on_success: =>
      view_arr  = []      
      @collection.each (tag_model) =>
        tag = new TagView {model: tag_model}
        view_arr.push tag.render().el
      @$el.empty().append view_arr
```

How would I change this to MarionetteJS collection view? I tried the following, and it doesn't seem to work?

```
  class TagListView extends Marionette.CollectionView
    el:"#tags"
    itemView:TagView

    onBeforeRender: =>
      @collection = new TagCollection
      @collection.fetch_data
        order_by : "name"
      , =>
        @render()
```

I'm simply removing the on_sccess() method, since my understanding is that the CollectionView will do the rendering of its items by its render method?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.

`The collection view binds to the "add", "remove" and "reset" events of the collection that is specified.` Once any of these events happend, collection view will automatically update the view, either part or entier.

Another thing you may want to know is in version 1.0.0, when a collection do fetch, it will not longer trigger the `reset` event by default. To get the old behavior, pass `{reset: true}`.